# Prerquisite for a chat box in android

Tags: android

I want to make application which can create dynamic chat boxes and group chat can be done.
Chat box should be deleted by the person who has created chat box and multiple chat box can run on server at a time.

If anyone can guide me step wise from where to start and which platform to use ,erlag language is one of the component i am planning to use.